# How to force activity to stay in Portrait mode only for tablet ( Pixel C) which has 360 degree rotation?

Tags: android, tablet, screen-orientation

Currently I have set screenOrientation="portrait" in android manifest. This works fine for all devices but for Pixel C tablet, the screen looks upside down (for portrait mode activity) when the device is held in 180 degree rotation position.

So, How do I force activity to stay in portrait mode only even if the tablet is held in rotated position? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have applied the orientation to the application element in your manifest file. Please declare that inside your Activity element along with configChanges as mentioned below for each of your activities. This should be done inside your manifest file - AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
     android:screenOrientation= "portrait"
     configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
 </activity>
```

Also add this to your Activity class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: I had declared that inside activity tag itself. I tried applying configchanges attribute as well but still no luck.

Comment: Then try in your activity something like this - setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: Tried that also.. but still it flips upside down if the tablet ( in particular pixel C device) is held in rotated position. the screen looks reversed.